# Calling rest API through vb.net desktop application

Tags: mysql, vb.net, rest

Please need a help, I don't know how to go about it.
See what I'm trying to do.
I have MySQL database hosted on an online server. I query my database directly from my VB desktop application to my online database which is not a secured approach. So I was advised to use rest API for my queries. The rest API will be connected to my database host and client ID and access token will be generated by the API which will be used to link to it from my vb.net desktop application. So my VB.net desktop application queries my rest API while the rest API queries the database and returns the result in json format.

The code should be able to perform the following task.

1. Select from a table with certain conditions
2. The code would be able to insert data into a table

I can't find VB.net code for this on Google, and this would be the first time of me trying this out.
Please I need code to implement it.
Thanks

Comment: So really the first question is, what sort of rest api do you have available on the sever.  Generally speaking that api will do all the data access & CRUD operations.  You would call methods on that api that you pass parameters to and returns results normally a json result.  It’s not really as simple as just talking to a rest api

Comment: I have created an account with apisentris and also linked my database to the api, generated client ID and access token. Now my problem is coding it in my VB program. Thanks for your response, I hope to have more help from you.

Comment: It’s a very broad topic.  There is a lot of research for you to do first.  Google “consumer rest api” and come back with specific problems.  Note; most examples in this space will be c# but concepts, methods and objects you use will all cross over

Comment: Thanks. This comment helped me a lot